# Sort and group XML Based on Attributes

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, attributes, linq-to-xml

I am working with LINQ to XML in C# and I need to do some sorting on the attributes of my xml nodes. My xml looks something like this.

```
<root> 
    <Claim key="1" carrier="carA" zip="34343" pages="1"/>
    <Claim key="2" carrier="carA" zip="34343" pages="2"/>
    <Claim key="3" carrier="carB" zip="34343" pages="4"/>
</root>
```

I can sort the xml using the orderby clause such as

```
 var query= from claim in root.Elements("Claim")
            let Key = claim.Attributes("Key").First().Value
            let Carrier = claim.Attributes("Carrier").First().Value
            let CarrierZip = int.Parse(claim.Attributes("CarrierZip").First().Value)
            let Pages = claim.Attributes("Pages").First().Value
            orderby Pages ascending, CarrierZip ascending, Carrier ascending
            select claim;
```

Then I get a list of the keys from query.

What I want to do is get collections of all the claims with 1 page, then all the claims with 2 pages and so on, but I do not know what the maximum number of pages can be.

can anyone help me out?

EDIT -

I changed my intial thought on how to accomplish this and I now would like the out put to resemble this.

```
List<List<List<List<int>>>>

All claims 
- 1 page
   -zip1
      -carr1
         -int claim key
         -int claim2 key
      - car2
   -zip2
      -car1
- 2 pages 
   -zip1
```

and so on. The trick is I need to query the nodes and get multiple groups out of it. Can this be done in my statement or is a series of statements required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add a `GroupBy` clause:

```
var query= from claim in root.Elements("Claim")
           let Key = claim.Attributes("Key").First().Value
           let Carrier = claim.Attributes("Carrier").First().Value
           let CarrierZip = int.Parse(claim.Attributes("CarrierZip").First().Value)
           let Pages = claim.Attributes("Pages").First().Value
           orderby Pages ascending, CarrierZip ascending, Carrier ascending
           group new { CarrierZip, Carrier, Key } by Pages;

foreach (var group in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Claims with {0} pages:", group.Key);
    foreach (var entry in group)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("  {0} {1} {2}", entry.CarrierZip, entry.Carrier,
                          entry.Key);
    }
}
```

EDIT: To get a `List<List<int>>` from this, you'd use:

```
var claims = query.Select(group => group.Select(x => x.Key).ToList())
                  .ToList();
```

Alternatively, if you don't need the CarrierZip and Carrier in the results, you can simplify the query and the listifying to:

```
var query= from claim in root.Elements("Claim")
           let Key = claim.Attributes("Key").First().Value
           let Carrier = claim.Attributes("Carrier").First().Value
           let CarrierZip = int.Parse(claim.Attributes("CarrierZip").First().Value)
           let Pages = claim.Attributes("Pages").First().Value
           orderby Pages ascending, CarrierZip ascending, Carrier ascending
           group Key by Pages;

var claims = query.Select(group => group.ToList())
                  .ToList();
```

Comment: This works as expected which is great but I am new to using LINQ and I am having trouble with taking the groups and using the "keys" for each claim how i want. basically I would like to create a List<List<int>> of all the keys in the correct order, so in the list the first spot is a list of the 1 page claims in the proper order, the second list is the list of 2 page claims, and so on.

Comment: I have been thinking about my approach to the problem i am working with and I think it would be better to have a different output. would it be possible to instead end up with a list of lists of ints, to set it up so i have a List that holds groups based on the # of pages, then inside those lists hold another set up lists that hold groups based on carrier zip, then the same thing based on carrier.   I will edit my question to show you my expected output.

Comment: @kds6253: You'd need an extra group by *within* the first group. I'm afraid I don't have time to keep changing my answer for changing requirements, but if you work through my existing answer carefully to make sure you understand it thoroughly (which you should do anyway) you should be able to make the change yourself.